# How to override Product model in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am working on `Sylius 1.2.8`. I have overridden Product model and it is working fine but when I add a new product with attributes:

```
<?php
...

$em = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.product');

/**
* @var \Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductAttributeValueInterface $attribute
* @var \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface $product 
*/

$product->addAttribute($attribute);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

It throws this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   sylius_product_attribute_value (locale_code, text_value,
>   boolean_value, integer_value, float_value, datetime_value, date_value,
>   json_value, product_id, attribute_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)' with params ["en_US", null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   "[\"013ea12a-1aff-4050-8107-20b53ada73ce\"]", null, 28]:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null
```

My custom Product Model looks like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;

class Product extends BaseProduct implements ProductInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And my config file:

```
sylius_product:
  driver: doctrine/orm
  resources:
    product:
      classes:
        repository: AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository
        model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

I have found a similar question asked :[stackoverflow.com/q/22919004/6248367](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22919004/6248367). But this does not solve my problem neither does it answer why application fails. This answer is also 4 years old. Can someone help me fix this?

**Edit**: This error is also thrown in admin whenever I create a new product and add attributes to it at the same time. Workaround is to first create product, then add attributes.

Comment: I have tried clean install of your Sylius version and add exact same config and its working fine. Is there any other thing that you have override? Try everything from scratch - resource.yml, Product entity that extends BaseProduct, Product repository that extends BaseProductRepository and proper Product.orm.yml configuration.

Comment: it seems like you need to set the product before adding an attribute because the product_id is not set yet. so persist the product before persisting the attributes

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani You're right but doctrine should automatically manage that internally. According to you If it was intended behaviour then how did admin's product creation break?

Comment: @czende I think you're right but I haven't got enough time to check all the configurations yet. I'll respond soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. As @czende mentioned properly check the configuration.

In my case I had set the wrong class in `subject` while overriding the `attribute`:

```
sylius_product:
  driver: doctrine/orm
  resources:
    product:
      classes:
        repository: AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository
        model: AppBundle\Entity\Product

sylius_attribute:
  driver: doctrine/orm
  resources:
    product:
        # Make sure to provide the correct Product class in the subject.
      subject: AppBundle\Entity\Product 
      attribute:
        classes:
          model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttribute
          repository: AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductAttributeRepository
```

Also make sure to use `mappedSuperclass` in the mapping config instead of `entity` as [commented](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3997#issuecomment-176151714) by [Michał Marcinkowski](https://github.com/michalmarcinkowski) in issue [#3997](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3997)

```
AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttribute:
  type: mappedSuperclass
  table: sylius_product_attribute
```

**EDIT**: To debug what's wrong, start by checking `warnings` in symfony `debug bar`. It can narrow down your search area for bug. It can also hint you if something is wrong in your configuration file.